# What is the better option (performance wise) Inline Scalar UDF, or Outer Apply in SQL 2012

Tags: sql, database-performance

I am currently using a bigger, more complex version of:

```
Select A.Address, A.City, A.State, A.Zip, S.MeterNumber, Ac.AccountNumber, C.CustomerName,
uci.fnGetAttribute(S.ServiceID, 'AMW') as Avg1Mw,
uci.fnGetAttribute(S.ServiceID, 'RateCode') as Rate

from Address a inner join Service s on a.addressid = s.serviceid
inner join vwAccountService v on s.serviceid = v.serviceid
inner join Account ac on v.accountid = ac.accountid
inner join Customer on ac.customerid = c.customerid
```

The function gathers the most recent attribute requested from a historical data table that has one entry per month.

Would an outer apply be a better choice here performancewise? Or is there a better construct for this?

Comment: Did you try out my answer? It's an amazing feature for testing the performance of queries against actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Write the queries you want to test

2) Click the ["Include Actual Execution Plan"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189562.aspx) button in SQL Server Management Studio

3) Run both queries and it'll display how they perform versus each other. One might say it uses 80% of the entire amount of resources used for both queries. That would mean the other one is a lot better.

Comment: This is what I will end up doing. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

My gut tells me that a CROSS APPLY, but the true test will be on how they perform against your actual data. It will depend, in part, of what the UDF is actually doing.

Comment: I had considered cross apply, but sadly there are instances where there will be no data returned from the other table due to non-existence. Cross acts like an inner join -- I can't lose the rows on the left just because there's nothing on the right.